# Moving text in a web form vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to do a label that will slide from left to right of a web form in vb.
I search on the web it only have example that work for windows application form..
I wanted it to be done in web form..
How should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try exploring *[marquee](http://jsfiddle.net/kgrmd/1/)*. Other can be using java script.

Answer (score 0):

There are no controls in ASP.NET for moving text as such..however you can use Marquee(depricated) or jQuery to achieve this..and it has got nothing to do with VB or c#..

http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html